# WiFi problem in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu

I am running a relatively fresh installation of Kubuntu 14.04 on my HP Inspiron laptop (I installed it about a month ago). It was working perfectly fine (except a couple of hiccups) for all this time, until last couple of days.

Now, some time after booting (say, 20 - 30 mins), the WiFi stops working -- sometimes it disconnects from the WiFi network, and goes into infinite loop of trying and failing to connect; or sometimes it shows that it's connected to the network although nothing works. If I try to manually reconnect to the network, it seldom works. If I disable and enable WiFi (from Kubuntu's network manager), it instantly connects to the network, but again, nothing works. The only solution is to reboot the computer, and it works just fine -- until 20-30 mins.

It's not a network problem, because WiFi works just fine on my Mobile. It's not even a hardware issue because WiFi works flawlessly on same laptop in Windows.

How do I fix this annoying WiFi issue? If you want me to run any commands, I can show the output.

Note: I don't think I installed anything new / changed anything in the configuration that might have destabilized WiFi.

Edit:

```
tan@tan-laptop:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804b]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
tan@tan-laptop:~$ uname -r
3.19.0-30-generic
tan@tan-laptop:~$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.19.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.19.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-346, 346.96, 3.19.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-346, 346.96, 3.19.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.5~trusty, 3.19.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Check now.

Comment: Try the suggestions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162026&p=12729812#post12729812)

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -r`?

Comment: @HeatherBrown It is a very old thread.

Comment: I was running Kubuntu 15.04 before, and I broke the installation by trying solutions from similar threads (which, I guess, didn't apply to my hardware). That's why I want to try solutions that are actually applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try another driver for this adapter. Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Comment: Do I need to reboot afterwards?

Comment: didn't seem to work. I installed and rebooted. Worked for some time, now same.

Comment: Well. There is no better driver so far. It may be a hardware issue, like antenna bad contact, etc.

Comment: But it works fine in Windows, so shouldn't be a hardware issue, right? Do you need to know output of any more commands? :\

Comment: I do not have any other solution. Maybe it is some kernel bug too. Try too boot with one of the previous kernels using grub.

Comment: Should the output of "kernel driver in use" from lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 change? It still shows rtl8188ee.

Comment: No. It is another version of the same driver.

Comment: @taninamdar Did it install without errors? Please give output of `dkms status`.

Comment: Seems so. Edited question to add output.

Comment: Try some older kernel. And you can try with `rtlwifi-new` and without it. You can remove it by `sudo dpkg -r rtlwifi-new-dkms`.